# The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed. while uploading docx, pdf file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

while uploading docx, pdf file, The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
My add function is:-

```
 public function add() {

    $this->load->helper('ckeditor'); // for loading ckeditor
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->validation_rules);
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {


        $file_name = '';


        if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {
            $this->load->library('upload', $this->fu_config);
            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->upload->display_errors());
                redirect('files/add', 'refresh');
            } else {
                $file = $this->upload->data();
                $file_name = $file['file_name'];
            }
        }



        // preparing for insertion
        foreach ($this->validation_rules as $k => $v) {
            $fields[] = $v['field'];
        }
        $data = $this->files_model->array_from_post($fields);
        $data['file'] = $file_name;



        if ($this->files_model->save($data)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'New Event Added Successfully.');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'sorry, Event cannot be Added.');
        }
        redirect('files/add/', 'refresh');
    } else {
        $files = new stdClass();
        // Go through all the known fields and get the post values
        foreach ($this->validation_rules as $key => $field) {
            $files->$field['field'] = set_value($field['field']);
        }
    }

    $data = array(
        'method' => 'add',
        'main_content' => 'form',
        'editData' => $files,
        'ckeditor' => array(
            'id' => 'description',
            'path' => 'js/ckeditor',
        )
    );
    $this->load->view('admin_wrapper', $data);
}
```

I tried to change system/libraries/Upload.php line 199:

> $this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]);
>   Change that line to:
>
> $this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]); var_dump($this->file_type); die();

I got out put this: -

> string(42) "cannot open `' (No such file or directory)"

How can i solve this error ?

Comment: upload library loaded with config,show the content of `$this->fu_config`

Answer (score 0):

make sure your `$this->fu_config` is correct,
example of the config :

```
$config['upload_path']          = './uploads/'; //Your file path for upload
$config['allowed_types']        = 'pdf|docx';
$config['max_size']             = 100;
$config['max_width']            = 1024;
$config['max_height']           = 768;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. but i replaced system/libraries/Upload.php file with codeigniter 2.1.2 as my project is in codeigniter 2.1.0. and it works.